# Scanner, FileOutputStream и чтение double

Tags: java, файлы, scanner, запись, fileoutputstream

Недавно изучаю Java. Набросал код который копирует double значения из одного файла в другой.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(reader.readLine()));
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(reader.readLine());

        while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
            double d = scanner.nextDouble();
            System.out.print(d + " ");
            fos.write((int)d);
        }
    }
```

Исходный файл:
3,1415 1,13315 2,222

Проблема в том, что в результирующий файл эти значения не попадают, но вместо них вставляется 3 пробела. Почему так происходит? Заранее благодарю.

Upd:

-Я сознательно оборачиваю FileOutputStream в scanner. Значений в файле предположительно может быть очень много, и другие известные мне подходы(побайтовое/построковое/буфферное чтение) либо неэффективны либо перерастают в огромную логику.

-Код не будет работать и без аргумента d: к примеру fos.write(11) даёт тот же результат.

-Пробовал вытащить запись в файл из цикла таким образом:

```
byte[] ar = new byte[3];
        int i = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
            ar[i] = (byte)(scanner.nextDouble());
            i++;
        }
        for (byte b:ar){
            System.out.print(b + " ");
        }
        fos.write(ar);
```

Вывод 3 1 2, результат не поменялся.

Полный код:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
             Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(reader.readLine()));
             FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(reader.readLine())) {

            while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
                double d = scanner.nextDouble();
                System.out.print(d + " ");
                fos.write((int) d);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать FileWriter и сделать как нибудь вот так...

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(reader.readLine()));
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(reader.readLine());


    while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
        double d = scanner.nextDouble();
        String s = d + " ";
        writer.write(s.replace('.', ','));

    }
    scanner.close();
    writer.close();
```

Comment: Попробовал, результат тот же.

Comment: @KirstenLy  а что в файле какой вывод?

Comment: Просто 3 пробела.

Comment: @KirstenLy А вы используете  writer.close;() ?

Comment: Scanner в try-with-resourses, этого не видно в коде. Да, тот же результат если вынести закрывашку отдельно.

Comment: @KirstenLy это действительно странно, у меня данный код работает. (windows 10)

Comment: @KirstenLy если не секрет можно скинуть мне полный код?  я протестирую у себя.

Comment: Не секрет. =)
Добавил полный код в первое сообщение, правда там мало что поменялось.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79146/discussion-between-minepolz320-and-kirstenly).